# create cascading dropdownlist from cached data

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

In my application I have written a main query like

```
 SqlDataAdapter cmd0 = new SqlDataAdapter(select a,b,c,d, from table1,sqlconn)
```

then I have cached this query since table1 is a very huge table and I don't want to call the database everytime user makes some change.

```
        DataSet ds0 = new DataSet();
        cmd0.Fill(ds0);
        DataView source0 = new DataView(ds0.Tables[0]);
        DataTable dt0 = new DataTable();
        cmd0.Fill(dt0);
        Cache["data"] = ds0;
```

I have 2 dropdownlists for a and b.
I get the cached column a and bind the data in the dropdownlists

```
 //dropdown for a
        DataSet dataset_a = new DataSet();
        dataset_a = (DataSet)Cache["data"];
        DataView dataview_a = dataset_a.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dataview_a.Sort = "a";
        DataTable datatable_a = dataview_a.ToTable(true, "a");
        ddla.DataSource = datatable_a;
        ddla.DataTextField = "a";
        ddla.DataValueField = "a";
        ddla.DataBind();
```

Now I try to populate dropdownlist for b initally by the same way as I did for ddla

```
//dropdown for b
        DataSet dataset_b = new DataSet();
        dataset_b = (DataSet)Cache["data"];
        DataView dataview_b = dataset_b.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dataview_b.Sort = "b";
        DataTable datatable_b = dataview_b.ToTable(true, "b");
        ddlb.DataSource = datatable_b;
        ddlb.DataTextField = "b";
        ddlb.DataValueField = "b";
        ddlb.DataBind();
```

when I change my selection in ddla(dropdownlist for a) I want the dropdown list for b also to be changed. (Cascading dropdownlists)

So basically I want to fire the query like:

```
Select b from table1 where a=ddla.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

but I don't kno how to do it with the cached data.

Please help me! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to same source and expect to get result you looking for.
To get what you want you need to unbind `ddlb`. And instead, on event `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedItemChanged` of `ddla` you should filter the rows from the data table and load into the `ddlb`.
There are actually few ways of doing it. One, is to have 2 tables in dataset and use relationship, with one combo bind to table `a` and another bind to table `b`. This way, when you click in `a`, the related rows will show up in `b`

Comment: thank you so much.Unbinding the dd1b and binding it again with dataview.rowfilter on SelectedIndexChanged event worked! Have been breaking my head on this since morning! Thank you again.